# Prove that $x$ and $x+1$ are coprime numbers

Tags: divisibility

Given $\{x \mid x > 1\}$, how do I prove that any given $x$ and $x+1$ are coprime?

Comment: $p \mid x,x+1 \Longrightarrow p \mid 1$.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If $y$ divides $x$ and $x+1$ then it divides $(x+1)-x=1$. Conclude.

Comment: "If y divides x and x+1 then it divides (x+1)−x=1." Why is this true?

Comment: If $y$ divides $x$ and $x+1$ then there's $a$ and $b$ such that $x=ay$ and $x+1=by$ then $(x+1)-x=(b-a)y$ so... Do you understand?

Comment: Nice! A one-liner kills the question!

Comment: Nice and concise.

Answer (score 17):

$\gcd(x,x+1)=\gcd(x,x+1-x)=\gcd(x,1)=1$.

Hence $x$ and $x+1$ are coprime.

Comment: +1 for a general method

Comment: I feel dumb, that I didn't get to it myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ is a multiple of $p$, then the next multiple of $p$ is $x+p$, but that's clearly larger than $x+1$.

Comment: Or, $ $  mod $\,p\!:\ x\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, x+1\equiv 1\not\equiv 0\ $ (else $\,p\mid 1-0)\ \ \ $